# Multidimensional Shape Preserving/Monotone Spline - Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, shapes

Does anyone know whether matlab has anything similar to PCHIP for multidimensional interpolation? I can use it for 1-dimensional interpolation. For multidimensional, matlab only allows me to use spline. The issue with splines is that they are not shape preserving. Below an example taken from [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/16/splines-and-pchips/) on why the difference between them is actually very important:

[image]